# You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders. is getting caused by OR assignment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

In my Typescript React code:

```
return changed ||= false
```

I keep getting this error when I use the operator `||=` (I think from webpack)

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (85:8)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     checkParams.forEach(param => {
>       return changed ||= false;
|     });
```

And the error disappears when I remove the `||=` operator

```
return changed = changed | false
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: if `return changed = changed | false` works then does `return changed |=false` give what you intend? it might just be `||` vs `|` but I am very confused what `changed` represents here.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen the return value isn't relevant, It only is needed to end the function execution. But I only wanted ot modify the variable `changed` which is a boolean variable. And the code here is over simplified form to recreate the error.

Comment: I am unable to understand why changing an operation to `||=` is causing webpack to give such error.

Comment: does `changed ||=false; return;` work? also can you edit your question to make it clearer it is webpack is giving the error not typescript or something else, that is an important detail that I had missed the first time.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Ok, I will edit the question. And this code you wrote doesn't work either. I even added an unrelated code `let a = false; a ||= false;` and it would break it too.

Comment: I run into the same problem with the ??= operator.